Template function member as template parameter
I want to call different template member functions with the same sequence of input types, in order to reduce boilerplate code, I tried to implement a dispatcher function, for_each_type,

struct A {
    template<typename T>
    void a() {}

    template<typename T>
    void b() {}

    template<template<typename> class Fn>
    void for_each_type() {
        Fn<char>();
        Fn<int>();
        Fn<float>();
        ...
    }
};

int main() {
    A obj;

    // This doesn't compile
    // obj.for_each_type<A::a>();
    // obj.for_each_type<A::b>();
}

Is it possible to implement such a function ?

You can't use template template parameters to identify a function template, but you could provide class templates that in turn return a function pointer to the correct instance of the function, here called a_ptr and b_ptr.
Example:
struct A {
    template<typename T>
    void a() {}

    template<class T>
    struct a_ptr {
        auto operator()() { return &A::a<T>; }
    };

    template<typename T>
    void b() {}

    template<class T>
    struct b_ptr {
        auto operator()() { return &A::b<T>; }
    };

    template<template<class> class Fn>
    void for_each_type() {
        (this->*Fn<char>{}())();
        (this->*Fn<int>{}())();
        (this->*Fn<float>{}())();
    }
};

Then, you'd need to provide the class template a_ptr or b_ptr instead:
int main() {
    A obj;

    obj.for_each_type<A::a_ptr>();
    obj.for_each_type<A::b_ptr>();
}

Demo

Not as elegant as I like, but it gets the job done.

@user416983 Glad to hear that it worked and I agree about the lack of elegance, but I can't think of way to do it without involving class templates in one way or another.

This can be achieved also with lambdas and then simplified more with macros. But the notion of elegance is a matter of one's taste. Some will say its way uglier and I totally understand why:
https://godbolt.org/z/4vzhq17T4

@alagner Yes, some kind of class templates, like generic lambdas as shown by Jarod42 or as regular class templates as shown in this answer, is probably necessary. I would stay away from macros, but as you point out, it's a matter of taste.

As alternative, you might use tag dispatching:
template <class F>
void for_each_type(F f)
{
    f(std::type_identity<char>{});
    f(std::type_identity<int>{});
    f(std::type_identity<float>{});
    // ...
}

struct A {
    template<typename T>
    void a() {}

    template<typename T>
    void b() {}
};


int main() {
    A obj;

    for_each_type([&]<typename T>(std::type_identity<T>){ obj.a<T>(); });
    for_each_type([&]<typename T>(std::type_identity<T>){ obj.b<T>(); });
}

Demo
